# Как избавится от лишних сетевых запросов в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router

Ребята, приветствую ) возникла одна проблема. не понимаю как ее решить. в проекте есть несколько связанных между собой страниц. есть страница поиска и при клике на иллюстранцию попадаем на страницу иллюстрации. используется react-router для роутинга и axios для отправки запросов. суть проблемы в том, что на внутренней страницы отправляются запросы, которые я сделал на странице поиска . т.е. почему запросы с одной странице вызываются и на другой странице . не могу этого понять. подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении искать проблему ? на странице иллюстрации сейчас в принципе нет запросов , но они отправляются. заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сложно судить по описанию, хорошо бы посмотреть на parent component страницы поиска и одиночной страницы и сетап роутинга.

Но это судя по всему, после клика по картинке происходит unmount компонента Browse, а потом, по какой-то причине он маунтится опять. Такое может происходить из-за неправильной иерархии путей у react-router (если используется v4).